# How to display user input string when questions ask for input in reverse order in C++

Tags: c++, string, input

I recently started learning C++. I must create a program that asks the user for their name and a file name after; then displays the file name with type (eg `.cpp`) 1st and the name after. Must be able to accept negative values.

I'm using repl.it to write the code 1st then pasting in to a `.cpp` file to compile. Then will compile it with the makefile using the command `make hello` and check that the generated program compiles and runs correctly.

Sample run:

```
What's your name? John
What's the name of the output file? gen
```

gen.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello John!\n";
}
```

Attempt:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string a;
   cout << "What's your name?\n";
   string b;
   cout<< "Whats the name of this file?";
   getline (cin,b);
   cout<<"//"<<b;
   getline (cin, a);
   cout << "Hello " << a;
   return 0;
}
```

Except it displays in the console:

```
What's your name?
Whats the name of this file? //e.g.c
//c
```

The output is wrong, so what mistake did I make? What's the correct method to get the expected values?

**Edit:** This is what the assignment says:

[image]

Comment: The order of the lines seems messed up. Shouldn't you `getline (cin, a);` directly after asking for the users name?

Comment: Look very closely at the order of your outputs and inputs. You are printing the two questions first, and _then_ calling `getline` twice. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to print // gen.cpp Before name so another example would be 1.name?mary then 2.outputfile name? hello; will show 3.//hello.cpp then 4.Hello Mary

Comment: @Human-Compiler yes I want it to show b before a as shown in sample run

Comment: @JanusP You now print `What's your name?\nWhats the name of this file?` and then wait for the user to enter the filename (I think - you should use more descriptive variable names. Rename the variables into something like `username` and `filename`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo problem is it only allows input at 2nd question when I want individual input per question

Comment: @JanusP No, this code will allow for two input lines. Are you showing the full code or are you using some formatted input somewhere ( `std::cin >> ...`)? Please rename the variables so we know what you expect in them. `a` and `b` doesn't say much.

Comment: What you're currently doing: 1. Print first prompt 2. Print second prompt 3. Read in second answer 4. Read in first answer 5. Print first answer. What it sounds like you want to do: 1. Print first prompt 2. Read in first answer 3. Print second prompt 4. Read in second answer 5. Print second answer 6. Print first answer.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Put the actual text (as text) in the question if it's important.

Comment: Btw, what does "_Must be able to accept negative values_" mean in this context?

Comment: @TedLyngmo By that I mean if user types a number for their file such as -3

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, your calls to `getline()` are in the wrong places.  Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string username;
   cout << "What's your name?\n";
   getline (cin, username);
   string filename;
   cout << "Whats the name of this file?";
   getline (cin, filename);
   cout << "//" << filename << ".cpp" << endl;
   cout << "Hello " << username << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, 1 missing aspect is the appending of the file type to the file name. e.g. instead of just //hello it should be //hello.cpp which is what i'm having trouble with also

Comment: That is simply a matter of adding `<< ".cpp"` after `<< filename`. I have updated my example to show this.